# CSS issue - How to Prevent Floating Objects from Wrapping in a Container, without changing size of container?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css

Here is my JSfiddle document:

http://jsfiddle.net/TSM_mac/xXcZx/1/

Basically, I am trying to make the second div slide in as the first div slides out.

I am having a problem with my CSS, the second div (because it is float: left) goes to the next line

The way to fix it would be to make sure that they always stay on the same line, but I cant figure this out :(.

Any suggestions?

Regards,

Taylor

Comment: Do you need to use `webkit-keyframes`? You can also do this via jQuery.animate

Comment: I am creating this for use on an iPhone as a webapp. Webkit animations are supported by hardware acceleration in the iPhone while jQuery animations are not. It doesn't run smooth, I already attempted that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/xXcZx/7/

I added a `<div id="wrapper">` around your other DIVs with `overflow:hidden` and removed the styling from `#container` and set its width dynamically with jQuery.

```
$('#container').width(function() {
    return $('.page').width() * $('.page').length;
});
```

Since you have the `.page` class on each of your DIVs you can use use that instead of each ID.

```
$('#move').live('click', function () {
    $('.page').addClass('slideLeftOut');
});
```

I'm not sure if it was your intention but after the webkit keyframe animation was complete it was going back to the start (Object 1). If your intention was to have "Object 2" remain in view after the animation is complete then try this...

```
.slideLeftOut {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 4s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Comment: you. are. fantastic. Thank you I have been trying so many different things, your solution is the only one that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the container, and then:

```
display: inline-block;
```

on the children.  Then you can play around with the margins, not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  But I'm not sure this is the most elegant way of doing it.  In any case, here's the version of your fiddle that doesn't wrap, let me know if I misunderstood:

http://jsfiddle.net/xXcZx/5/

Comment: yeah :/ that didn't seem to do it. The children are not staying in the same line

Comment: yes, sorry I was very unclear. I meant the elements inside of the #container